# INS-20802 Oracle Database configuration Assistant failed

Tags: oracle

Oracle Database 19c installer

---

[INS-20802] Oracle Database configuration Assistant failed

Cause: The plug-in failed in its perform method
Action: Refer to the logs or contact Oracle support Services.

Log File Location
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2023-09-19_04-53-29PM\installActions2023-09-19_04-53-29PM.log
Answer:: I checked This file is empty

---

---

Look at Progress Menu

Look at the log file

C:\oracle\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\orcl.log

In this file I found following data:::::::::::::::::

[ 2023-09-19 17:00:10.560 IST ] [WARNING] [DBT-11209] Current available memory is less than the required available memory (3,229MB) for creating the database.
[ 2023-09-19 17:00:30.022 IST ] [WARNING] [DBT-06208] The 'SYS' password entered does not conform to the Oracle recommended standards.
[ 2023-09-19 17:00:30.023 IST ] [WARNING] [DBT-06208] The 'SYSTEM' password entered does not conform to the Oracle recommended standards.
[ 2023-09-19 17:00:30.023 IST ] [WARNING] [DBT-06208] The 'PDBADMIN' password entered does not conform to the Oracle recommended standards.
[ 2023-09-19 17:00:30.978 IST ] Prepare for db operation
DBCA_PROGRESS : 8%
[ 2023-09-19 17:00:31.740 IST ] Copying database files
DBCA_PROGRESS : 31%
[ 2023-09-19 17:04:09.954 IST ] Creating and starting Oracle instance
DBCA_PROGRESS : 32%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 36%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 40%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 43%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 46%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 100%
[ 2023-09-19 17:13:07.427 IST ] [FATAL] Error while executing "C:\oracle\db_home\rdbms\admin\dbmssml.sql". Refer to "C:\oracle\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\dbmssml0.log" for more details. Error in Process: C:\oracle\db_home\perl\bin\perl.exe
DBCA_PROGRESS : 31%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 8%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 0%

---

---

"C:\oracle\db_home\rdbms\admin\dbmssml.sql"

CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY dbms_sumadv_lib AS 'C:\oracle\db_home\bin\oraqsmashr.dll';
/

In this file I founded the following

---

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmU05.jpg)

"C:\oracle\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\dbmssml0.log"

In this file i found the following.....
This file is showing Empty......

---

---

C:\oracle\db_home\perl\bin\perl.exe
In this execution file i opened but its empty....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPbAs.jpg)

While installing oracle 11c the following exception raised please help me regarding this issue

Thanks
Gopi

Comment: Can't help but focus on the earliest warning: `[WARNING] [DBT-11209] Current available memory is less than the required available memory (3,229MB) for creating the database.` You should probably resolve that situation first if you've got no other clues from the logs.